# How do I add sticky alert box?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want an independent alert notification sticking just below header regardless of the content of the page.

If you notice the notification bar is going inside the header white space. What is the best way to load this toaster?

I have tried to create a whole page environment where there's a header a left sidebar and a right sidebar.

Can someone help? Your suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Bill

```css
    .top-head {
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
      background: #FFFFFF;
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
      height: 50px;
    }

    .top-head h1 {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 26px;
      font-weight: 600;
      line-height: 50px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .top-menu-right {
      float: right;
    }

    .top-head .user-bar {
      text-align: right;
      float: right;
    }

    .top-head .user-bar a {
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 49px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 0 7px;
    }

    .top-head .user-bar a:hover {
      color: #02b875;
    }

    .top-head .user-bar a i {
      margin-right: 6px;
    }

    .top-head .user-bar .ping {
      background: #02b875;
      border-radius: 50%;
      height: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 9px;
      top: 13px;
      width: 10px;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .top-head .user-bar img {
      float: left;
      height: 32px;
      width: 32px;
      margin-top: 7px;
    }

    .notification-bar {
      padding: 1.1rem 1.25rem;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 15px !important;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .notification-bar a {
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .notification-danger {
      background-color: #dd4b39;
      color: #F1F1F1;
    }
    
    
.left-sidebar {
  background: #353752;
  text-align: center;
  color: #a0a3b3;
  font-size: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 8% 0 5%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="top-head fixed-top">
      <div class="container container-responsive">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- Brand Logo -->
          <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-3 logo-bar">
            <h1><a href="index.php"><strong>Logo</strong></a></h1>
          </div>


            </nav><!-- END OF NAV BAR -->
           </div><!-- END OF TOP MENU RIGHT -->
          </div><!-- END OF COLUMN USER-BAR -->
        </div><!-- END OF ROW -->
      </div><!-- END OF CONTAINER -->
    </div><!-- END OF NAVIGATION -->

    <div class="notification-bar notification-danger">
       Please enter a valid email address.
    </div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-3 left-sidebar"></div>
<!-- START OF RIGHT PANEL -->
<div class="col-9">
   <p>Hello World</p>
</div><!-- END OF .col-9 -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add the below css in .notification-bar class.

```
position: absolute;
top: 58px;
```

Comment: I tried that. But the notification is not sticking just like the header. When I tried scrolling the notification didn't stick under header but it rather scrolled underneath the header: http://prntscr.com/n55fjk

Comment: Do you want position: fixed ??

Comment: Position sticky perhaps?